# Возможна ли проверка при генерации словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Паршу примерно такой HTML при помощи BeautifulSoup:

```
[<div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title" style="width: 115px;"><span>Артикул</span></div>
<div class="spec_value" style="width: 165px;"><span>LED-LP-100M-15CM-12V-F</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Тип светодиода</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>DIP 5 мм</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Кол-во светодиодов</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>666 шт</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Кол-во мерцающих светодиодов</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>100 шт</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Шаг</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>15 см</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Рабочее напряжение</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>12 вольт</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Цвет провода</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>Прозрачный</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Максимальный отрезок</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>25 м</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Длина бухты</span></div>
<div class="spec_value"><span>100 м</span></div>
</div>, <div class="spec" style="margin-top:10px;">
<div class="spec_title"><span>Цвета</span></div>
<div class="spec_value colors">
<div class="colors_wrapper">
<div class="color_el" title="Синий"><span style="background: #005b94;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="Красный"><span style="background: #b91016;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="Желтый"><span style="background: #f4d600;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="Зеленый"><span style="background: #7ebf00;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="Белый"><span style="background: #ffffff;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="Теплый белый"><span style="background: #f3f1d6;"></span></div>
<div class="color_el" title="RGB"><span style="background: url('/img/product/rgb.png');"></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>]
```

Генерирую словарь:

```
    specials = {
        i.find('div', 'spec_title').text :
            i.find('div', 'spec_value').text for i in special
            }
```

Получаю такой результат:

```
{'Тип светодиода': 'DIP 5 мм', 'Шаг': '15 см', 'Кол-во мерцающих светодиодов': '100 шт', 'Цвета': '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 'Артикул': 'LED-LP-100M-15CM-12V-F', 'Цвет провода': 'Прозрачный', 'Кол-во светодиодов': '666 шт', 'Рабочее напряжение': '12 вольт', 'Максимальный отрезок': '25 м', 'Длина бухты': '100 м'}
```

'Цвета' есть не на каждой странице, и хотелось бы проверять key перед записью в словарь, чтобы запустить ещё один цикл, который бы собрал все #цвета.

Подскажите, возможно ли вообще при генерации словаря совершать проверку key или value ?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем ясен. Попробуйте *минимальный* пример создать. Если вопрос именно о словаре, то уберите html и просто руками список для примера составьте. Если вопрос именно о html, тогда переформулируйте вопрос и укажите что именно и из какого (минимального) html вы хотите получить (не указывая *как* итоговые данные получаются, а только *что* вы хотите получить). В любом случае, укажите явную проблему с кодом: что вы хотите получить (буквальный результат), что вместо этого ваш код делает (подробно).

Comment: @jfs, задача состоит в том, что необходимо проверить key перед тем, как произойдёт запись в словарь, и если key == чему-то, то запустить ещё один цикл.

Comment: от того что вы повторите, что уже написали, яснее вопрос не станет. Прочтите мой комментарий ещё раз и попробуйте следовать его рекомендациям насколько можете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
obj2 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

dt = {k: v if not k == 3 else {a: b for a, b in obj2} 
      for k, v in obj1}

print(dt)
>>> {1: 2, 3: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, 5: 6}
```